# jQuery Click Cell to Change into Text Box

Tags: jquery

I have been looking on Google and StackOverflow but haven't been able to find what I'm after as of yet. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

What I have is a table with 5 rows

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row" class="table-check-cell"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="table-selected-1" value="1"></th>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>Address 1</td>
    <td>10th Feb 2011 (10:43am)</td>
    <td><ul class="keywords">
        <li class="pink-keyword">Awaiting Reply</li>
        <li class="purple-keyword">Direct</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>(Notes Text)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="table-actions">
        <a href="#" title="View" class="with-tip"><img src="images/magnifier.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
        <a href="#" title="Edit" class="with-tip"><img src="images/pencil.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
        <a href="#" title="Validate" class="with-tip"><img src="images/navigation.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
        <a href="#" title="Close" class="with-tip"><img src="images/cross-circle.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I am looking to do is be able to edit the `<td>(Notes Text)</td>` value in the table cell by clicking on it so it changes to an input box (displaying currently what is in the cell) so it can be edited and saved again by clicking off it.

I have a (very) basic knowledge in jQuery but fine with the updating side of things using PHP / MySQL.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: is this a simple html/jquery page? or do you have like php or .net going on in the background?

Comment: Its actually a snippet from an admin panel with the table contents generated from PHP

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possible way:

```js
$('td:contains("(Notes Text)")').click(

  function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('');
    $('<textarea />').appendTo($(this)).val(text).select().blur(

      function() {
        var newText = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().text(newText).find('textarea').remove();
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="table-check-cell">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="table-selected-1" value="1" />
      </th>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>Address 1</td>
      <td>10th Feb 2011 (10:43am)</td>
      <td>
        <ul class="keywords">
          <li class="pink-keyword">Awaiting Reply</li>
          <li class="purple-keyword">Direct</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>(Notes Text)</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="table-actions">
        <a href="#" title="View" class="with-tip">
          <img src="image/magnifier.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" title="Edit" class="with-tip">
          <img src="images/pencil.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" title="Validate" class="with-tip">
          <img src="images/navigation.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" title="Close" class="with-tip">
          <img src="images/cross-circle.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

While the above works, I'd heartily recommend applying a class to the `td` element that you'd like to be able to edit (assuming you want to be able to edit more than one cell).

Failing that: you could just use the `contentEditable` attribute in the html:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="table-check-cell">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="table-selected-1" value="1" />
      </th>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>Address 1</td>
      <td>10th Feb 2011 (10:43am)</td>
      <td>
        <ul class="keywords">
          <li class="pink-keyword">Awaiting Reply</li>
          <li class="purple-keyword">Direct</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td contentEditable>(Notes Text)</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="table-actions">
        <a href="#" title="View" class="with-tip">
          <img src="image/magnifier.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" title="Edit" class="with-tip">
          <img src="images/pencil.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" title="Validate" class="with-tip">
          <img src="images/navigation.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" title="Close" class="with-tip">
          <img src="images/cross-circle.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Edited** in response to question from OP (in comments):

> One tiny (I hope) other question was, is there any way to move it from being a `textarea` to and `input`?

Yep; that's pretty easily accomplished:

```js
$('td:contains("(Notes Text)")').click(
  function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('');
    $('<input type="text" />').appendTo($(this)).val(text).select().blur(
      function() {
        var newText = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().text(newText), find('input:text').remove();
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="table-check-cell">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="table-selected-1" value="1" />
      </th>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>Address 1</td>
      <td>10th Feb 2011 (10:43am)</td>
      <td>
        <ul class="keywords">
          <li class="pink-keyword">Awaiting Reply</li>
          <li class="purple-keyword">Direct</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>(Notes Text)</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="table-actions">
        <a href="#" title="View" class="with-tip">
          <img src="image/magnifier.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" title="Edit" class="with-tip">
          <img src="images/pencil.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" title="Validate" class="with-tip">
          <img src="images/navigation.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" title="Close" class="with-tip">
          <img src="images/cross-circle.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note the change from `$('<textarea />')` to `$('<input type="text" />')` although the `type` attribute may not be *strictly* required (since `input` elements default to `type="text"` anyway). Also the `find('input:text')`.

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
- [`select()`](http://api.jquery.com/select/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Just tried out the demo, looking good. How could I get that to update using ajax so when you click off it saves back to the database?

Comment: I suspect that's a *whole other question.* And would suggest asking (or, at least searching for) such a question. Sorry. :)

Comment: One tiny (I hope) other question was, is there any way to move it from being a <textarea> to and <input>?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some of the edit-in-place plugins. For example:

- [jQuery Editable](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Editable)
- [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("td").bind('click', function(oTd){
      var c = $(oTD).text();
      $(oTd).empty();
      $(oTd).append('<input type="text" value="' + c + '"/>");
   )};
});
```