# Replace a title with an input and update the title on the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to replace a title when clicking on it by a text input in order to modify the title and then submit the modification to the database, I'm using this code :

```
<div style="font-size: 70%;"><h2 class="outer"><?php echo $designation; ?> </h2></div>
```

this div is loaded using another script and therefore is not on the original page, so I think we must use the delegate method.

Here is the jquery script I'm using to turn its background color to pink:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#right").delegate("h2","click",function(){
       $("h2").css("background-color","pink");
     });
  });
 </script>
```

Any idea how to replace the title in this div by a text input tag ? and any idea how to submit the modification to the database once I click outside the input field ?
thank you

Comment: For the first part, you might want to look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033732/jquery-click-cell-to-change-into-text-box for updating it in the database, you will have to add code to construct an AJAX request that will update the information in the database.

Comment: Your javascript must be in separate `<script></script>` tags to your linked jquery. If you're wanting to trigger it with a click, you need to add the `onclick` event to your code.

Comment: Don't use `$` as a prefix to your variables.

Comment: Can you please point me to a cibled tutorial, 
all the Jquery tutorial I have checked are too general

Comment: All of the code in your script tag is ignored, since you specified a src.

Comment: 'How to submit the information to the database' is a pretty big question. If you don't know anything about databases i would suggest finding a tutorial about php/MySQL.

Comment: I pretty good with php/mysql my problem is with Jquery, I asked the second question only to check if there is a faster way to do it using maybe a script.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no click handler in you code, you can use `.on()` method
- You should use another script tag for loading .js files, your markup is invalid
- `input` element doesn't have closing tag, you should remove the `</input>`

  ```
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){ // When the DOM is ready
        $(".outer").on('click', function() {
           if ( this.children.length ) return;
           var text = $.trim(this.innerHTML);
           $("<input>").val(text)
                       .appendTo($(this).empty())
                       .focus();
        }).on('blur', 'input', function() {
           // Listening to blur event 
           // for replacing the element with it's value
           $(this).replaceWith( $.trim(this.value) );
        })
     })
  </script>
  ```

http://jsfiddle.net/3FKzH/

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me, could it be the Jquery source, 
I don't know much about Jquery I downloaded the compressed Jquery file and stored it in my project folder under the name : "jquery-1.10.2.min.js"

Comment: Maybe the problem is here : if ( this.children.length ) return;
Because I have the feeling it returns without doing anything.

Comment: @TarikMokafih Have you checked the browser's JavaScript console? It works for me, have you checked the demo in my answer?

Comment: I have this error message on the consol : GET http://localhost/test/jquery-1.10.2.min.map
But in separate small page I created it works even with the error message

Comment: @TarikMokafih That's a HTTP error, so this means the library is loaded, `map` files are loaded for debugging purposes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found

Comment: I pretty sure now that it's working when the content of the html tag is simple text, but when the content is a php script ( <?php echo $var?>) it's not working

Comment: @TarikMokafih Well, my answer assumed that `h2` elements only have text content not element.

Comment: thank you anyway it helped me being more familiar with Jquery