# jQuery: generate Select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with data, and when I click on a cell in a certain column, I want it to change into a select dropdown for the user to choose a category for that row (which will be written to the database by AJAX but that'll come later).
I've done something similar before with text boxes using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033801/3683178), which works great, but I'm not sure if I'm modifying it correctly.

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrY24/1/) which shows the problem I'm having. I click on the text and it turns into a select element as expected, but when I click on that to choose an option, the dropdown doesn't stay open and I can't select anything. Debugging has shown me that when I click the dropdown, it runs the `$("td.ChooseType").click()` routine again so I've tried to suppress that by removing the class then adding it back on on selection, but that hasn't solved it. On the rare occasion that the dropdown stays open, I am unable to select anything by either mouse or keyboard.
All of the users will be on IE8 unfortunately, so I need it to be compatible with that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), as otherwise that click event is always bound to that `td` - regardless of whether its class changes.

Simply change:

```
$("td.ChooseType").click(function() {
```

To:

```
$("table").on('click', '.ChooseType', function () {
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PrY24/3/).

Comment: Actually what's the point of event delegation here..? `.ChooseType` is not a dynamically created element. i can't find any difference between the original fiddle and yours. can you elaborate..?

Comment: @TJ the difference is what's explained in the answer. If you check out jb455's JSFiddle demo you'll see that he uses the non-delegated `click()` function, which retains that function on the `td` element even after the class has been removed. If you attempt to select an option (in Chrome) the `select` element will open and close instantly as the non-delegated event causes the `select` element to be recreated.

Comment: Ok, got it. I'm using safari 6.1.3 but strangely this is not happening! 0__0 . that's why i asked..

Comment: Ah, that's great thanks! Though it wasn't working initially, I realised we were running an old version of jQuery which didn't support `.on()`. The dropdown still does sometimes flash on & off on click but is normally fine after a couple of goes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Purely as an alternative to the accepted answer, you can remove an attached handler with [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/). So instead of adding and removing the class, you could unbind and rebind your handler. Only requirement is that the function can't be in-line, but has to be declared separately.

example: http://jsbin.com/qiqunici/1/edit

```
var handler = function () {
    $(this).unbind('click', handler); //unbind the clicked element only

    //create and change the element

    //inside the select-change event, instead of addClass, re-attach:
    {
       //$(this).parent().addClass("ChooseType").text(selected).find('select').remove();
       $(this).parent().click(handler).text(selected).find('select').remove();
    }
};

$("td.ChooseType").click(handler);
```